# How can I round up the numbers of mysql table, leaving the two decimals to zero. it's possible?

Tags: mysql, rounding

I need round up the numbers of a complete table of mysql with a funtion leaving the two decimals to zero?

e.g.:

from `75,55` to `86,00`

from `75,45` to `75,00`

All the prices of a complete table changed a few decimal and I do not know how it happened.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: How does 75,55 go to 86,00 ?

Comment: Maybe `76,00` typo

Comment: Hint: [`Round(75.45, 2)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`Round(X, D)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) function. From Docs:

> Rounds the argument X to D decimal places. The rounding algorithm
>   depends on the data type of X. D defaults to 0 if not specified. D can
>   be negative to cause D digits left of the decimal point of the value X
>   to become zero.

Try:

```
SELECT ROUND(75.45, 2);
-- Fetches 75.00

SELECT ROUND(75.55, 2);
-- Fetches 76.00
```

Now, it seems that you want to `Update` all the values of a particular column, by rounding them to two decimal places. You can do the following:

```
UPDATE your_table_name 
SET your_column_name = ROUND(your_column_name, 2);
-- It will round all the values to 2 decimal places.
```

Comment: I sorry. I get 0 rows affected. I got confused with some that I had made by hand.
I use UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = ROUND(`column_name`, 2); and 0 rows affected

Comment: I tried ROUND (column_name, 1) its work, changed the last decimal digit and rounded but it does not work with "2" maybe by collation? Type decimal(16,2)

Answer (score 0):

"UPDATE your_table_name SET your_column_name = ROUND(your_column_name, 2);" not work for me. I dont know.
**¡SOLUTION!** = TABLE > ESTRUCTURE > NAME COLUMN > length/values > remove decimal. 
All number round up in my row (column). Them I put decimal again. All my fields it's ok.